# quarkus reactive mutiny thread pool management

Tags: java, multithreading, quarkus, mutiny

Background: I'm just this week getting started with Quarkus, though I've worked with some streaming platforms before (especially http4s/fs2 in scala).

Working with quarkus reactive (with mutiny) and any reactive database client (mutiny reactive postgres, reactive elasticsearch, etc.) I'm a little confused how to correctly manage blocking calls and thread pools.

The quarkus documentation suggests imperative code or cpu-intensive code to annotated with `@Blocking` to ensure it is shifted to a worker pool to not block the IO pool. This makes sense.

Consider the following:

```java
public class Stuff {
  // imperative, cpu intensive
  public static int cpuIntensive(String arg) { /* ... */ }

  // blocking IO
  public static List<Integer> fetchFromDb() { /* ... */ }

  // reactive IO
  public static Multi<String> fetchReactive() { /* ... */ }

  // reactive IO with CPU processing
  public static Multi<String> fetchReactiveCpuIntensive(String arg) {
    fetchReactive() // reactive fetch
      .map(fetched -> cpuIntensive(arg + fetched)) // cpu intensive work
  }
}
```

It's not clear to me what happens in each of the above conditions and where they get executed if they were called *from* a resteasy-reactive rest endpoint without the `@Blocking` annotation.

---

Presumably it's safe to use any reactive client in a reactive rest endpoint without `@Blocking`. But does wrapping a blocking call in `Uni` accomplish as much for 'unsafe' clode? That is, will anything returning a `Multi`/`Uni` effectively run in the `worker` pool?

(I'll open follow-up posts about finer control of thread pools as I don't see any way to 'shift' reactive IO calls to a separate pool than cpu-intensive work, which would be optimal.)

**Edit**

This question might imply I'm asking about return types (`Uni`/`Multi` vs direct objects) but it's really about the ability to select the thread pool in use at any given time. [this mutiny page on imperative-to-reactive](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/guides/imperative-to-reactive) *somewhat* answers my question actually, along with the [mutiny infrastructure docs](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/guides/infrastructure) which state that "the default executor is already configured to use the Quarkus worker thread pool.", and the [mutiny thread control docs](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/guides/emission-threads) handles the rest I think.

So my understanding is this:

If I have an endpoint which *conditionally* can return something non-blocking (e.g. a local non-blocking cache hit) then I can effectively return any way I want on the IO thread. But if said cache is a miss, I could either call a reactive client directly or use mutiny to run a blocking action on the quarkus worker pool. Similarly mutiny provides control to execute any given stream on a specific thread pool (executor).

And reactive clients (or anything effectively running on the non-IO pool) is safe to call because the IO loop is just subscribing to data emitted by the worker pool.

Lastly, it seems like I could configure a cpu-bound pool separately from an IO-bound worker pool and explicitly provide them as `executor`s to whichever emitters I need. So ... I think I'm all set now.

Answer (score 1):

This is very good question!

The return type of a RESTEasy Reactice endpoint does **not** have any effect on which thread the endpoint will be served on.
The only thing that determines the thread is the presense of `@Blocking` / `@NonBlocking`.

The reason for this is simple: By just using the return type, it is not possible to know if the operation actually takes a long time to finish (and thus block the thread).
A non-reactive return type for example does not imply that the operation is CPU intensive (as you could for example just be returning some canned JSON response).
A reactive type on the other hand provides no guarantee that the operation is non-blocking, because as you mention, a user could simply wrap a blocking operation with a reactive return type.